# Server side rendering (isomorphic, universal ) in React.JS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have an app in react js (created by create-react-app and ejected). And I am also using react-route and react-redux. I need to convert it to SSR (server side render isomorphic universal). 
Any suggestions ?

Comment: [NextJS](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/)

Comment: ok but dont want to refactor whole app, is there any way to add ssr without changing whole app ?

Comment: If you want to add SSR, there will be some refactoring needed irregardless of what you decide to use.

Comment: ok thanks but i think there are another solution

Comment: @ArmenAsaduryan, this is a very broad question that is not going to get an answer unless you narrow it down to what specific aspect of the SSR project are you wanting suggestion on? Server configuration? Do you have some code you want to us to look at? Adding navigation? How to integrate support for Redux? What server-side data loading looks like? Authentication with SSR? You see what I mean?

Comment: @Daniel i am started project on create-react-app and on some stage i eject it for webpack configs, also im use react-routers Redux and using axios for request to API, i want change it to SSR for SEO, at this moment crollers see only index.html meta tags, for this project it is important

Comment: @ArmenAsaduryan, please share your `package.json` file. Are you using an ExpressJS server? Please share the code for that.